# Constructing an annual cycle/radial diagram in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, charts

I would like to make a diagram like [the below](http://www.louisianafolklife.org/images/atchaf_an_wheel.jpg) in PowerPoint, but I can't figure out how to draw the curved boxes (like the ones that say "Fishing" or "Trapping" in the chart).

#### Diagram

[image: ss of diagram]

Does anyone have a template I can use or a good method?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is far beyond the standard charting power of Microsoft Powerpoint (Take a look at [posted templates](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/templates/cycle-diagram-TC010174326.aspx)). If you want to complete it in Powerpoint, I would recommend using a combination of

1. **Shapes** for the concentric circles and the lines
2. **Wordart** to render the text `Text Effects -> Transform -> Follow Path`.

Once you create one text item to your liking, you can copy and paste the result, rather than having to start a new Wordart from scratch.

If you just want to create the chart, regardless of software, I would suggest attempting to create the chart using a suitable vector drawing program such as [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/download/?lang=en).